# Orphan letters in output of Greek text using betababel

Tags: fonts, packages, texlive, betababel

Snipped from the document I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{betababel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\bcode{Schisma}

\bcode{Σχίσμα}

\end{document}
```

No matter what I try Greek UTF-8 chars i get ΣχίσμαJJ i.e. the word is always followed by two upper latin "J".
If i use the German spelling  "Schisma" i get  σvξηισvμα.
I want just Σχίσμα and nothing more.
Can't get what's going on.

Comment: Make a complete example instead of showing snippets -- that makes it much easier for us to test.

Comment: added \begin{document} and \end{document} to make snippet a working example

Comment: The problem is independent from KOMA-Script, because it occurs with `book` instead of `scrbook` too. But it seems to depend on `betababel`.

Comment: Try `\bcode{Sxi/sma}` or `\bcode{*Sxi/sma}`. In the `betababel` documentation it states "As those (Greek characters) are usually not supported as input characters, there exist some transliteration codes to describe the Greek characters and diacritics by representing them by Latin characters and ASCII signs."

Comment: You are simply not supposed to use the Greek alphabet in the argument to `\bcode`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't need the betababel package. At least this seems to work as intended:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{betababel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}Schisma}

{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}Σχίσμα}

Und hier geht der Text weiter. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is good enough for me. Will use this with Greek UTF-8 chars. But why is it, that the German spelling results in two unwanted greek chars? It is just wrong Greek.

Answer (score 1):

The package documentation is clear: in the argument of `\bcode` or inside the `betacode` environment you are only supposed to use Latin characters and the symbols for accents and other diacritics.

The `J` appears because the package internally uses it as a delimiter (the character is supposed *not* to appear in the context of betacode), but the multibyte UTF-8 characters confuse the parser. And there's nothing one can do about it.

Just use `\textgreek`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}

% fix a bug of betababel
\toks0=\expandafter{\bcode}
\edef\bcode{\noexpand\leavevmode\the\toks0}
% end of fix

\begin{document}

\bcode{*sxi/sma}

\textgreek{Σχίσμα}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I added a fix to `\bcode` that wouldn't start a paragraph, which you can see if you typeset (without the fix)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}

\begin{document}

Some text with indent

\bcode{*sxi/sma} and following text

Some text with indent and \bcode{*sxi/sma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see the paragraph starting with `\bcode` is not indented. The output is correct if the fix is added.

[image]